# Use Dplyr::Bind_Rows and Purrr to Selectively Bind Different Dataframes In a List of Dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I'm attempting to use tidyverse tools to selectively bind a list of dataframes using dplyr::bind_rows(). I'll split the mtcars dataset to create a basic reproduction of my real data.

```
Df<-mtcars%>%
split(.$carb)%>%
head()
```

I can bind it together with bind_rows()...

```
Df<-Df%>%
bind_rows()
```

But how do I selectively bind elements of the list. What I want to do is create two lists - the first binds list elements 1,3,6 while the second binds 2,4,8. 
I'm thinking something like...

```
Df<-Df%>%map(~bind_rows(.x,list(.$`1`,.$`3`,.$`6`),list(.$`2`,.$`4`,.$`8`)))
```

But this code is obviously not correct so I would appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy approach is to just map with one fixed argument in an implicit function.

```
picker <- list(c('1', '3', '6'), c('2', '4', '8'))
my_out <- map(picker, ~'['(Df, .x) %>% bind_rows) 

my_out %>% print
```

which based on the other answers is I think what you want now:

```
[[1]]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
3  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
5  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
6  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
7  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
8  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
9  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
10 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
11 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6

[[2]]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
2  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
4  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
5  15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
6  15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
7  19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
8  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
9  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
10 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
11 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
12 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
13 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
14 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
15 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
16 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
17 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
18 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
19 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
20 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
21 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Note: I originally was very confused by whether you wanted what I call `picker` to be *indices* of the list or you wanted to *names* of the list.  This confusion was just an artifact of the way `split()` names lists and probably doesn't apply to your real data.

Comment: I haven't had too much time to fully test this but I'm not sure it does what I'm looking for. I simply want to stack (using bind_rows) dataframes 1, 3, and 6 in the list, and dataframes 2,4,8, resulting in a list of two dataframes. Does your approach do this? I don't need to mix any rows.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  In that case your job is way easier than I thought (if I understand correctly now.) I'll update my answer.

Comment: Answer edited.  I notice my output is the same as @jazzuro, except for the last rows of each dataframe.  Which is the correct output?

Comment: @jazzuro's is correct. I like your solution, but not sure why it's messing up the last part? On quick inspection, it looks like it's doing 1,3,8, for the first part, instead of 1,3,6?

Comment: Oh, I see.  `split()` (used to create the sample data) creates a named list, where the names are the values of `carb` (i.e. integers).  Do you want the first, third, and sixth element from the list [i.e. c(1, 3, 6) are indices], or the list elements _named_ `1`, `3`, and `6` [i.e. the data frames where `carb == 1`, `carb == 3`, and `carb == 6`?]??

Comment: This works ... picker <- list(c(1,3,5),c(2,4,6))...I guess it just refers to the number of the dataframe in the list and not the actual name? My real data will have actual names for each dataframe, and not numbers, so this way seems to work, so I can accept your answer...

Comment: I can match the other output by doing `map(picker, ~'['(Df, as.character(.x)) %>% bind_rows)`.

Comment: Thanks, the "as.character" part is helpful as well. I accepted the answer, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This could be another way. I tried to reflect your `map()` theme here. I used `Map()` in base R. If you want to use the `purrr` package, I think you can try `map2()`.

```
foo <- mtcars %>% split(.$carb)

Map(function(x, y) bind_rows(foo[c(x, y)]), c(TRUE, FALSE), c(FALSE, TRUE))

map2(.x = c(TRUE, FALSE), .y = c(FALSE, TRUE), .f = ~ bind_rows(foo[c(.x, .y)]))

[[1]]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
3  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
5  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
6  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
7  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
8  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
9  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
10 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
11 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6

[[2]]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
2  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
4  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
5  15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
6  15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
7  19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
8  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
9  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
10 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
11 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
12 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
13 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
14 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
15 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
16 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
17 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
18 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
19 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
20 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
21 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I haven't been able to get it to work using purrr's map yet...

Comment: @Mike Now I am playing around and trying to figure out how `map()` option works. I tried the following idea with `map2()`. `mtcars %>% 
split(.$carb) %>% map2(.x = c(TRUE, FALSE), .y = c(FALSE, TRUE), .f = ~ bind_rows(.[c(.x, .y)]))`. This does not work since `.` does not indicate the list object passed from the previous code. If we clearly specify the list object, the `map2()` idea works. `foo <- mtcars %>%  split(.$carb); map2(.x = c(TRUE, FALSE), .y = c(FALSE, TRUE), .f = ~ bind_rows(foo[c(.x, .y)]))`.

Comment: @Mike One more try with `pmap()`. This does not work either. However, the content of the error message is different from the case of `map2()`. `mtcars %>% split(.$carb) %>% pmap(.l = ., .f = function(x, y) bind_rows(.[c(x, y)]), x = c(TRUE, FALSE), y = c(FALSE, TRUE))`.  It seems to me that breaking up pipes seems necessary here.

Comment: @Mike I took a bit of time and thought about your question. The only option I have is the following. `map2(.x = c(TRUE, FALSE), .y = c(FALSE, TRUE), .f = ~ bind_rows(split(mtcars, mtcars$carb)[c(.x, .y)]))`. If you give up passing data with %>% and put everything in `map2()`, things work in your favor.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much thought into this...I like it, just not sure about the "c(FALSE, TRUE) idea? I guess it's telling the code to alternate for the join, but it doesn't allow for mixing the binding of the various dataframes in the lists in many different ways? My example was too simplistic...I was hoping for a method that would allow me to selectively bind any of the dataframes...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I realised that OP has given this as just an example and originally, the starting point is from

```
Df<- mtcars%>% split(.$carb)
```

The original solution would still work, if we do

```
lst <- list(x = c(1, 3, 6), y = c(2, 4, 8))

Df %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  split(.$carb %in% lst[[1]])
```

But is there a way we can bind them according to `lst` directly ?

I am not an expert in `tidyverse` but after going through through the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/purrr.pdf) , I found a function `invoke_map` which can give what we want here.

```
invoke_map(list(
  function(x){x %>% map(. %>% filter(carb %in% lst[[1]])) %>% map_df(c)},
  function(x){x %>% map(. %>% filter(carb %in% lst[[2]])) %>% map_df(c)})

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 11 x 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
# 2  21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
# 3  18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
# 4  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1     4     1
# 5  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1     4     1
# 6  21.5     4 120.1    97  3.70 2.465 20.01     1     0     3     1
# 7  27.3     4  79.0    66  4.08 1.935 18.90     1     1     4     1
# 8  16.4     8 275.8   180  3.07 4.070 17.40     0     0     3     3
# 9  17.3     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.730 17.60     0     0     3     3
#10  15.2     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.780 18.00     0     0     3     3
#11  19.7     6 145.0   175  3.62 2.770 15.50     0     1     5     6

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 21 x 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
# 2  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0     4     2
# 3  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2
# 4  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1     4     2
# 5  15.5     8 318.0   150  2.76 3.520 16.87     0     0     3     2
# 6  15.2     8 304.0   150  3.15 3.435 17.30     0     0     3     2
# 7  19.2     8 400.0   175  3.08 3.845 17.05     0     0     3     2
# 8  26.0     4 120.3    91  4.43 2.140 16.70     0     1     5     2
# 9  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77 1.513 16.90     1     1     5     2
#10  21.4     4 121.0   109  4.11 2.780 18.60     1     1     4     2
# ... with 11 more rows
```

gives us the expected output. There could be better ways to optimize this, I am not sure.

---

**Original Answer :**

Why not change your `split` step? Get the output without using `bind_rows()`.

```
lst <- list(x = c(1, 3, 6), y = c(2, 4, 8))

mtcars %>%
  split(.$carb %in% lst[[1]])


#$`FALSE`
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

#$`TRUE`
#                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#Merc 450SE     16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL     17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC    15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

Comment: I only used "split" to create fake data and it doesn't apply to my real data. So for this question, you have to start from the list. I like your idea though...is there a way to use it with bind_rows?

Comment: @Mike I just realised it. Check my updated answer and see if it solves the issue.